# Python search pattern in string

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hello could please help me? I am trying a lot of days to make a script that finds a pattern.

My script is:

```
<meta content="" property="news_keywords"/>
<meta content="Tough and Truthful - Bostonians read the Boston Herald for solid reporting, whether in print or online, on the issues affecting their daily lives. The Boston Herald gets people talking. Our reporters are second-to-none, our photographers are Pulitzer Prize-winning and we present news that Bostonians care about and respond to." property="description"/>
<meta content='{"link":"http:\/\/bostonherald.com\/","type":"frontpage"}' name="parsely-page"/><meta content="" property="keywords"/>
<meta content="Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)" name="generator"/>
<link href="http://www.bostonherald.com/" rel="canonical"/>
<link href="http://www.bostonherald.com/" rel="shortlink"/>
<meta content="420" http-equiv="refresh"/>
<link href="http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/default/files/images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"/>
<title>Boston Herald | Boston Herald</title>
<style media="all" type="text/css">@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/modules/system/system.base.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/modules/system/system.menus.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/modules/system/system.messages.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/modules/system/system.theme.css?nd76bo");</style>
<style media="all" type="text/css">@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/modules/aggregator/aggregator.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/modules/comment/comment.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/modules/date/date_api/date.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/modules/date/date_popup/themes/datepicker.1.7.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/modules/field/theme/field.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/modules/mollom/mollom.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/modules/node/node.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/modules/poll/poll.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/modules/user/user.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/modules/views/css/views.css?nd76bo");</style>
<style media="all" type="text/css">@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/modules/ctools/css/ctools.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/modules/lightbox2/css/lightbox.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/modules/panels/css/panels.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/modules/rate/rate.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/libraries/superfish/css/superfish.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/libraries/superfish/css/superfish-vertical.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/libraries/superfish/css/superfish-navbar.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/modules/views_slideshow/views_slideshow.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/modules/jcarousel/skins/default/jcarousel-default.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/modules/panels/plugins/layouts/twocol_stacked/twocol_stacked.css?nd76bo");</style>
<style media="all" type="text/css">@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/themes/ike_omega/css/basics.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/themes/ike_omega/css/custom_blocks.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/themes/ike_omega/css/navigation.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/themes/ike_omega/css/view-story_slots.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/themes/ike_omega/css/taxonomy/taxonomy-styles.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/themes/ike_omega/css/bhr.css?nd76bo");</style>
<style media="print" type="text/css">@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/themes/ike_omega/css/print.css?nd76bo");</style>
<style media="all" type="text/css">@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/themes/omega/alpha/css/alpha-reset.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/themes/omega/alpha/css/alpha-alpha.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/themes/omega/omega/css/formalize.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/themes/omega/omega/css/omega-branding.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/themes/omega/omega/css/omega-forms.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/themes/ike_omega/css/layout-front.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/themes/ike_omega/css/global.css?nd76bo");</style>
<style media="all" type="text/css">@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/themes/ike_omega/css/ike-omega-alpha-default.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/themes/ike_omega/css/ike-omega-alpha-default-normal.css?nd76bo");
@import url("http://www.bostonherald.com/sites/all/themes/omega/alpha/css/grid/alpha_default/normal/alpha-default-normal-24.css?nd76bo");</style>
```

The pattern is

```
<meta content(+.?)refresh">
```

The string is so big so i tried with different approaches but neither works. I don't like to save the string in any txt file.

The script I tried but they didn't work.

```
#Try 1
import re
re.findall("<meta content(+.?)refresh">",html)

#Try 2
matching = [s for s in html if "<meta content(+.?)refresh">" in s]
```

Comment: _"i tried with different approaches but neither works."_ Show us.

Comment: Also, styling your code a little would help significantly.

Comment: Escape your quotation mark

Comment: What you want is not clear.

Comment: Sorry, I would like to grab out the section of the string that start with "meta content" and finishes with "refresh">". Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 0):

The question from the comment was: 'I would like to grab out the section of the string that start with "meta content" and finishes with "refresh">".'

I split it into lines because that way ^ matches the start of each line, not the whole string. I used ^ to match the start and $ to match the end. In fact these are probably not necessary since the < and > would be sufficient. Also note that the double quote is escaped by the slash character before it.

Another key point: it's not +.? but .*? that will work to grab all the characters in the middle of the string.

```
>>> import re
>>> for line in html.splitlines():
...     m = re.match("^<meta content(.*?)refresh\"/>$", line)
...     if m:
...         print(m.group(0))
...
<meta content="420" http-equiv="refresh"/>
```

The docs on Python regular expressions can be found here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html